# Non-ActiveRecord nested model form not taking model values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails' `form_for` and `fields_for` to get a form for a nested `json` attribute the model has, but I'm not getting the value when editing and have to set the value manually:

```
<%= f.fields_for :json do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.text_field :attr, value: @app_configuration.json.attr %>
<% end%>
```

In order to get my json attr to be readable I do this on my controller:

```
    @app_configuration.json = OpenStruct.new(JSON.parse(@app_configuration.json))
```

Why do I have to manually assing the value?

How does `ff.text_field` look for the attribute value?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be using the builder variable `ff` declared using `fields_for`.

```
<%= f.fields_for :json, @app_configuration.json do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.text_field :attr %>
<% end%>
```

Using `f.text_field :attr` will look for `attr` in the parent model which does not exist and the reason why you don't see values during edits.

For non AR, custom objects you also need to pass in the second parameter to `fields_for` as shown.  Please see documentation on [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but that was a copy/paste mistake from me. I'm  using the builder variable `ff`. Just updated the code.

Comment: Could you inspect the form's object and make sure the value exists?  You could check this in the controller with `logger.debug { obj.inspect }` or in the view file with `<%= f.object.inspect %>` after the `form_for` declaration.

Comment: I just tried `<%= ff.object.inspect %>` and it outputs nil. if I write `<%= f.object.inspect %>` it outputs the full object, but it doesn't seem to work with the `ff` builder. The problem seems related to this.

Comment: I transform the `json` attribute to be an `OpenStruct`, can that be a problem?

Comment: What values do you get for `<%= f.object.json.inspect %>` right before the `fields_for` declaration?  I'm wondering if the association is loaded.

Comment: I get an `OpenStruct` with all the key/values for the `json` attr. Interesting.

Comment: Ah, so `json` is not a model.  My bad, all this time I was thinking `json` was a model.  I'm inexperienced in this.  Could you refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763867/using-rails-form-helpers-with-serialized-custom-classes

Comment: Thanks! that worked. Could you write that as an answer so I can accept it? Basically I had to write `<%= f.fields_for :json, @app_configuration.json do |ff| %>`.