# Module vs wrapper in a hash extension to access key values as attributes

Tags: ruby

I'm new in Ruby and I'm being a bit dissapointed that Hash values can't be accessed as objects (myHash.key), as pointed out in many other questions (example: [How do I use hash keys as methods on a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240535/how-do-i-use-hash-keys-as-methods-on-a-class)).
I don't like the openstruct solution cause its not recursive, and I don't want to modify the Hash class.

Therefore I've developed the following solution. First define the following module:

```
module NiceHash
  def method_missing(name, *args, &blk)
    if args.empty? && blk.nil? && self.has_key?(name.to_s)
      result=self[name.to_s]
      if result.is_a? Hash
        result.extend(Nice_Hash)
      end
      return result
   else
     super
   end
  end
  def respond_to?(sym, include_private = false)
    super(sym, include_private) || (self.has_key?(sym.to_s))
  end
end
```

And then use it with

```
a={"a"=>"a"}
a.extend(NiceHash)
a.a
```

The solution works.

My question is: this could be also done with a wrapper class. Which would be the better? My I found any (hidden) problem with the given solution.

Comment: Think about hash with keys like "-", "." etc. Hope you now understand why it is not possible to access hash values with the method syntax.

Comment: How does this work with hash keys that are arrays? Or `Regexp`s? Or hashes themselves? Or keys which aren't valid method names? Or a key named `to_s`?

Comment: Have a look at http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Struct.html

Comment: @greg-dan and Jörg I'm using this class for YAML, or JSON parsed data, where there are not "-", nor ".", not object keys. So I'll not face this problem, but its a good restriction to know.

Answer (score 0):

Responding to your question about hidden problems with your solution, there are two main ones.

1. As other people have mentioned in comments, it will break when the keys are not valid ruby method names.
2. Your solution is based on method_missing, just like OpenStruct is. Therefore it's subject to the same shortcomings. As stated in the [OpenStruct docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html):

> An OpenStruct utilizes Ruby’s method lookup structure to and find and
>   define the necessary methods for properties. This is accomplished
>   through the method method_missing and define_method.
>
> This should be a consideration if there is a concern about the
>   performance of the objects that are created, as there is much more
>   overhead in the setting of these properties compared to using a Hash
>   or a Struct.

Comment: I'm not saying it does, I'm saying that your solution is subject to the same performance issue because they're both based on method_missing